# Fill na in pandas where another column column value is not in list

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
     'Name': ['A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B'],
    'Include':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
    'Category':['Cat','Dog','Car','Dog','Bike','Dog','Cat','Bike'],
    })

df
```

[image]

I am trying to fill the `Include` column with the string `yes` if the column `Category` does not match the following list:

```
exluded = ['Car','Bike']
```

So that my expected output is this:

[image]

Any ideas of how to achieve this? THanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and a boolean mask:

```
df.loc[~df['Category'].isin(exluded), 'Include'] = 'yes'
print(df)

# Output
  Name Include Category
0    A     yes      Cat
1    B     yes      Dog
2    A     NaN      Car
3    B     yes      Dog
4    A     NaN     Bike
5    B     yes      Dog
6    A     yes      Cat
7    B     NaN     Bike
```

Alternative with `np.where`:

```
df['Include'] = np.where(df['Category'].isin(exluded), np.nan, 'yes')
```

Comment: I was about to suggest this, more efficient than `where` ;)

Comment: I would have guessed that :) Maybe `np.where` is faster than `loc`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
     'Name': ['A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B'],
    'Include':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
    'Category':['Cat','Dog','Car','Dog','Bike','Dog','Cat','Bike'],
    })

exluded = ['Car','Bike']

# check the condition and fill if it fails
df.Include = df.Include.where(df.Category.isin(exluded), 'yes')
df
```

[image]